# Legend for ListContourPlot

Tags: legending

Consider this example below for ListContourPlot.

```
ListContourPlot[
  Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, 0.02}, {j, 0, Pi, 0.02}], 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

I wish to make the Legend look like this:

[image]

I have searched the net but did not find any way of doing this. I'm sure this can be done because that legend in the link is created using *Mathematica* but I can't figure out how.

Maybe it's something very trivial but I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this because I always had a hard time dealing with legends in *Mathematica*.

The example that I gave above was just for illustration. My actual function 
is more like this:-

```
ListContourPlot[
Table[Cos[Sqrt[bx^2 + by^2]], {bx, -1, 1, 0.1}, {by, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
ContourLabels -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All]]
```

So the plot looks like this:-

[image]

This legend has clear color bands which can be separated like that shown in
the legend above.

So my question is whatever may be the case can we make a legend that looks 
like the one I showed.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Version Number : 9.0.0.0

Comment: @Pinguin Dirk : i hav edited my question ,pls hav a look at it.

Comment: ok, @swish's answer kind of opens my eyes what you want (why is another question :) ), sorry for being so complicated

Comment: @PD Just remembered this quote “Science answers the ‘how’ question.  The ‘why’ question is just a silly question.  The question is an inappropriate one.” -Richard Dawkins.                             Anyways thank you for ur time &   effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm sure you can move from here and make the legend you desire.

```
(*Make your plot*)    
plot = ListContourPlot[
   Table[Cos[Sqrt[bx^2 + by^2]], {bx, -1, 1, 0.1}, {by, -1, 1, 0.1}], 
   ContourLabels -> All, ColorFunction -> "LakeColors"];

(*Specify your legend labels*)
labels = Range[0.1, 1, 0.1];

(*Make legend*)    
legend = SwatchLegend["LakeColors", labels, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> {{15, 15}}, LabelStyle -> {Italic, 12}];

(*Combine them together*)
Legended[plot, legend]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this(SwatchLegend) is what i was looking for,Merci.